# multiple draggable rectangles matlab: extra rectangle

Tags: matlab

I am working on a code to get positions of multiple draggable rectangles inputted by the user. The code is working completely fine. However after pressing on the pushbutton, the code doesn't move forward until you draw one more rectangle. The problem I believe is `pos = uint32(wait(h));` statement waits indefinitely for another position and pushbutton handle is taken into consideration only after drawing another rectangle. I do need the `wait (h)` statement as `getposition` function doesn't work well for me. I really appreciate any help that you can provide, following is the part of my code.

Code:

```
im_des=rgb2gray('image_name.jpg');
ButtonHandle = uicontrol('style','push','String', 'STOP',...
'callback','set(gcbo,''userdata'',1,''string'',''DONE!'')', ...
'userdata',0) ;

while(1)
  if get(ButtonHandle,'userdata')
        break ;
  end

  h = imrect;
  pos = uint32(wait(h));

  if ~isempty(pos)    
      rectangle('Position', pos, 'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','k');
      for i=1:4
      counter=counter+1;
      array (counter) = pos(i); 
      end
      delete(h);
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the reason for needing to draw an extra rectangle after pushing the Stop button and I've found a couple of possible solutions to fix the problem.

In few words, the problem is that ... MatLab is faster than you.

In more words, this is what happen, step by step:

Let's suppose you want to draw just one rectangle, then push the "Stop" pushbutton to stop drawing.

The condition in the `if` statement at the beginning of the `while` loop is not verified (you have not pushed the button yet), so the the loop continues.

```
if get(ButtonHandle,'userdata')
   break ;
end
```

The `imrect` statement is then executed

```
 h = imrect;
```

it starts the rectangle drawing process: you can draw the rectangle, move it, resize it ans so on.

As soon as you start drawing the next statement is executed

```
pos = uint32(wait(h));
```

the `wait` function blocks the MatLab command line until you `double-click` on the rectangle to exit from the drawing mode

If you've drawn a valid rectangle, the next statement draws the actual rectangle, stores the rectangle's position in "array" and delete the `handle` to the `imrect` object

```
if ~isempty(pos)    
   rectangle('Position', pos, 'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','k');
   for i=1:4
      counter=counter+1;
      array (counter) = pos(i); 
   end
   delete(h);
end
```

At this point you you decide to "Stop" adding rectangles and push the "Stop" pushbutton.

Here is the point at which MatLab is ... faster than you.

While you are moving the muose's cursor to reach the pushbutton, the executioin of your script continues and a new iteration of the `while` loop starts.

Again the first statement is executed

```
if get(ButtonHandle,'userdata')
```

if you was not so fast (and you can not be) to reach the "Stop" pushbutton and push it before the new iteration starts, the `if` condition is not verified, therefore 
      the `imrect` sequence is executed

```
h = imrect;
pos = uint32(wait(h));
```

as your intent was to draw another rectangle.

This is the "additional" rectangle that "seeem" be required to actually stop the script after pushing the "Stop" pushbutton.

While the MatLab command line is blocked by the `wait` function, the `callback` listner is not, so you can push the pusshbutton and the value of `userdata` is set to `1`
 nevertheless, the drawing process has been activated.

Therefore you need to draw the "additional" rectangle, double-click to exit from `wait` so that anoter iteration of the `while loop can start.

At this point, eventually, the `if` condition is verified and the `break` statement stops the execution of the `while` loop.

This is what happens.

I've found two possible solutions: the first one allows keeping your script "almost" as it is, the second one implies to chenge the `GUI` concept.

The first solution allows you ... being faster then MatLab.

If you insert a `pause` statement after the call to `wait` (e. g. `pause(3)`) you will have 3 seconds to reach and push "Stop" before a new iteration starts.

This allows che `callback` setting `userdata` to be set to 1 and make the `if` condition at the beginning of the `while` loop being verified stopping the executin of the script without having to draw any additional rectangle.

The second solution consists in changing the behaviour of the `GUI`:

You can remove the `while` loop and change the `pushbutton callback` so that it takes care of calling `imrect` and plot the rectangle (in practical terms, you have to move
the code inside the `while` loop in the `pushbutton cllback`.

This way the behaviour of the GUI will be: any time you want to add a rectangle, you have to push the `pushbutton`

Here after, you can find the script of both the solutions.

Notice, I've made few additional modification to your additional code, in order to make it running:

I've removed the `uint32 cast`: having not a picture in the axes, the default `axes` limits are [0 1], 
if you convert `pos` to `unsigned 32-bit integer`, pos will be [ 0 1 0 0]

Also I've removed the `for` loop to store `pos` in `array`: it is not actually needed.

**Solution #1**

```
% Commented since in the code excerpt is not used
% im_des=rgb2gray('pdb_img_1.jpg');
ButtonHandle = uicontrol('style','push','String', 'STOP',...
   'callback','set(gcbo,''userdata'',1,''string'',''DONE!'')', ...
   'userdata',0) ;

% Added initialization of "array" and array_32" arrays
%    array_32: stores the rectangle pos as uint32
%    array: stores the rectangle pos as double (added to make the script
%    running without an image on the axes)
array=[];
array_32=[];
%
while(1)
   if get(ButtonHandle,'userdata')
      break ;
   end

   % Commented type cast (default axix limit are [0 1] therefore
   %    pos=[ 0 1 0 0]
   h = imrect;
   %    pos = uint32(wait(h));
   pos = wait(h);

   % added message display and "pause" statement to allow pressing "Stop"
   % button before drawing next rectangle
   disp('Press STOP within 3 sec. to stop')
   pause(3)

   if ~isempty(pos)
      rectangle('Position', pos, 'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','k')
      % if needed the edge color of each rectangle can be different
      %       rectangle('Position', pos, 'LineWidth',1,'EdgeColor',[rand(3,1)])
      %
      % Commented "for loop" to store rectangle pos since it is not needed
      %       for i=1:4
      %       counter=counter+1
      % "array" is built as (N x 4) matrix, each row contains the "pos" of
      % a rectangle (remove ";" to store it as a (1 x N) array
      array = [array ; pos]
      array_32 = [array_32 ; uint32(pos)]
      %       end

      delete(h)

   end

end
```

**Solution #2**
**Main script**

```
array=[];
axes
ButtonHandle = uicontrol('style','push','String', 'Add rect',...
   'callback','tmp=add_rect;array=[array;tmp]');
```

**Pushbutton callback**

```
function pos=add_rect()
h = imrect;
pos = wait(h);
rectangle('Position', pos, 'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','k')
delete(h)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. I just saw your solution today. I too implemented the pause function. Thanks a lot for posting your answer and all your effort

Comment: You're welcome! It was a very interesting question which allowed me learning something new.